# In what language is CryptoKitties programmed?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to understand what I would need to develop a program similar to CryptoKitties. As I understand it uses JS to connect to Metamask and uses its own private blockchain for kitties entity.

I know CS and I am learning JS ES6 and would like to understand what I would need to develop a similar application.

Also I am curious what I would need apart from Swift if I want to developed a similar program for Ios. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smart contract part is coded in [`Solidity`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/). The web ui connect with the blockchain by using JS, specifically [`Web3.js`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html). By the way, it's made of three different smart contract:

1. [The core smart contract code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#code).
2. [The sale auction](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb1690c08e213a35ed9bab7b318de14420fb57d8c#code).
3. [The sire auction](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc7af99fe5513eb6710e6d5f44f9989da40f27f26#code).

Answer (score 2):

Crypto Kitties is programmed in Solidity, which is a programming language used to create smart contracts on the Ethereum Blockchain.

Have a look at the docs to get started:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/